# Finding solution of equation with differentials

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the point of maximum exponential curvature, where the exponent equation is:

y = 0.2e^(0.4x)

I know the equation for this point is:

k = y'' / [(1+y')²]^(3/2)

How can I code this in mathematica to solve for the point?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Corse

Comment: I suggest you make attempts. You will receive assistance if you hit a stumbling block but a request for code, particularly in such a case you could almost transliterate the functions you require before maximization will not be received favourably and be closed unless you provide your sticking point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a pure request for coding without evidence of attempt to code or definition of problem in writing code.

Comment: Yes, this really needs some code effort. With that added I'd be happy to see it reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Mathematica version 10 you could do it as follows:

```
y[x_] := 1/5 E^(2/5 x)

sol = Maximize[ArcCurvature[{x, y[x]}, x], x]
(* {8/375 Sqrt[2/3] E^(1/2 (-3 Log[2] + 4 Log[5])), {x -> -(5/4) (3 Log[2] - 4 Log[5])}} *)

Plot[y[x], {x, -5, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[{sol[[2, 1, 2]], y[sol[[2, 1, 2]]]}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]